# Desktop shortcut creator - distributable via email

Tags: windows, email, clickonce, shortcut-file

I would like to create a shortcut to a web app (URL) on the desktops of a large number of clients.

The present-day solution of service-desk operators doing it for them via TeamViewer is not sustainable.

Ultimately, they should click a link in an email and the shortcut should be created on the desktop. I was thinking along the line of a little Click-Once app. The link will be to the app's install page where they will have to download and run the setup file. I'm concerned that email servers may tag such a mail as dangerous. In addition, Click-Once introduces unnecessary complexities i.t.o security, framework dependencies etc.

Any better suggestions?

**What I have tried:**

I built a click-once app that creates a desktop shortcut, but it is fairly cumbersome given a large number of client machines and potential compatibility en dependency complications.

Comment: I think you're trying too hard. Attach the shortcut file to the email. "Save as".

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, tried this, but email servers block this file attachment.

Comment: Then send a link to the shortcut.